# Programmatically uncheck jQuery UI checkbox button

Tags: jquery, user-interface, button, checkbox

I have an HTML checkbox element on my page like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="locked" /><label for="locked">Locked</label>
```

And I make a call inside my $(document).ready() to change this to be a jQuery UI checkbox button like so:

```
$('#locked').button({
    'icons': {
        'primary': 'ui-icon-unlocked'
    },
    'label': 'Unlocked'
});
```

Background context being that the user can use this button to lock/unlock a particular entity so that a background process will not alter it and it starts with an 'Unlocked' status. If javascript is not turned on, the user sees a checkbox and the label 'Locked' next to it.

I want to be able to programmatically check/uncheck this checkbox button. I've tried:

```
$('#locked').attr('checked', false);
```

But the checkbox button does not update to reflect the underlying control's checked status.

I could test the checkbox's checked property then do a .click() if it doesn't match what I want but that doesn't sound very elegant.

Comment: JQuery UI's Button on INPUT shouldnt change any HTML. So what ur writing should be possible. Could you write more of the check/uncheck you are using?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('#locked').removeAttr('checked');
```

It's just a guess to your case, but usually works for me like a charm.

EDIT: Taking a look at jQueryUI documentation, here is a method you should also try after changing programatically the state of the checkbox:

```
$('#locked').button( "refresh" )
```

"Refreshes the visual state of the button. Useful for updating button state after the native element's checked or disabled state is changed programatically."

Comment: The combination of removeAttr and button('refresh') worked. Many thanks!

Comment: Just FYI... button and buttonset both support the "refresh" command!

Comment: [In current versions of jQuery](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-), this will not produce the desired behavior. You *must* use [`.prop()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7389350/901048) instead.

Answer (score 15):

jQuery 1.5.x and earlier: `$('#locked').attr('checked','');`

jQuery 1.6.0 and later: `$('#locked').prop('checked', false);`

The `checked` attribute is considered a property, and has its own method now. You should use `.prop()` if it's available to ensure the desired behavior is observed by your users.

Answer (score 2):

Use the new **.prop()** function in **jQuery 1.6+**:

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

or with id

```
$('#myCheckboxId').prop('checked', false);
```

For **jQuery 1.5 and below**

```
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked','checked');
$('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of JQueryUI the `checkboxradio()` function must be used with the `refresh` option like so:

```
$("#selector").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

in order to update the checkbox visually after `.prop("checked", true);` or `.prop("checked", false);` has been used to check or uncheck the checkbox itself.

Source:  The API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/

> refresh()
>
> Refreshes the visual state of the widget. Useful for updating after the native element's checked or disabled state is changed programmatically.